# load balancing with Bird

Tags: routing, bgp, bird

I have the following routes pushed into my edge router

```
192.0.10.0/32      via 192.168.166.110 on br166 [master01 22:53:55] * (100) [AS64514?]
                   via 192.168.166.116 on br166 [worker_03 22:53:55] (100) [AS64514?]
                   via 192.168.166.114 on br166 [worker_01 22:53:55] (100) [AS64514?]
                   via 192.168.166.115 on br166 [worker_02 22:53:55] (100) [AS64514?]
```

The neighbours advertize the address `192.0.10.0/32`

What I'm trying to achieve is to load balance traffic through all those neighbours. It is still not clear whether it is something possible. For instance in this gist https://gist.github.com/bufadu/0c3ba661c141a2176cd048f65430ae8d it is achieved using the `maximum-paths` rule but this rule is specific to Ubiquiti Edge Router and I could not find anything similar on Bird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you are looking for `merge paths` configuration option of the `kernel` protocol.

Of course this will only work if your OS supports ECMP in FIB.

Comment: Ok I need to try that option. My OS is a Linux machine Debian 11 and it should support that.

Comment: I have enabled but unfortunately in my case it did not work but @Tomek I think you are right that is the option to use. The only problem is that I have failure to push the routes into the kernel. no idea why though.